# Jquery iframe source doesnt work on mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In my webpage am dynamically assigning  src to the iframe using jquery.

```
<iframe id="Frame" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>

$('#Frame').attr('src', URL);
```

This works perfectly on IE and chrome, but this doesn't work on Mozilla.

When I see console there is a warning:

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented
>   instead. in Browserlink:37"

I tried resolved this warning in my code base by changing "getPreventDefault" to "defaultPrevented"  but no luck.

My mozilla version is 48.0.

Surprisingly, when I open developer tools then Iframe loads.

Comment: Can you share the complete javascript piece of code? Where `URL` variable came from? How do you are setting the URL?

Comment: Have you tried    `document.getElementById('Frame').src = URL;` ?

Comment: Hi Perez, URL is coming from hidden variable and am able to see the URL in the alert box for the particular method, but while assigning to Iframe it doesn't load the content.

Comment: Hi nizzik, I even tried that, but no luck.